# How I can access to raw samples in Google Exoplayer

Tags: android, fft, exoplayer, spectrogram

I'm using Google Exoplayer 2.
How can I access to raw 16-bit samples of audio stream, i.e. to perform FFT for spectral analysis (creating spectrogram)?
Need I reimplement HandleBuffer of AudioSink (i.e. implement my version of DefaultAudioSink)?
Or need to add my implementation of AudioProcessor interface with side effect?
Or maybe another audio playing framework exists, more suitable to perform this task?
Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this? I am trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note: You can check [TeeAudioProcessor](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/audio/TeeAudioProcessor.AudioBufferSink.html) and you may be able to implement a TeeAudioProcessor.AudioBufferSink that does whatever visualization is needed.
[example](https://medium.com/@subasharyc/easy-visualizer-with-exoplayer-b310e73f677f)

Answer (score -1):

I did something similar, and wrote a blog post about it. You can check it out [here](https://medium.com/@mahmoud.mohamed.bahaa/diving-into-exoplayer-getting-more-control-over-the-framework-cac436d1472c).